# Working Swift code returns "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" when put in function

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a piece of Swift code I want to use throughout my application, so I wanted to put it in a function that returns either True or False to a @State variable that toggles a SwiftUI sheet.

I've checked that the code works outside of a function, but when put in a function and called to the @State variable, it returns the error "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context." I can't figure out exactly what this error means, but I get it with every function I've tried.

Assigning function return to @State variable:

```
self.welcome = saveProj(
    filename: $filename,
    base: $base,
    targets: $targets,
    strings: $strings
)
```

Declaring function:

```
func saveProj(filename: String, base: String, targets: Array<String>, strings: Dictionary<String,Dictionary<String,String>>) -> Bool {
    
    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    let name = filename + ".localproj"
    let file = paths[0].appendingPathComponent(name)
    
    var output = ""
    output += "base: " + base + "\n"
    output += "targets: [" + targets.joined(separator:",") + "]\n"
    strings.forEach { language, translations in
        output += language + ": ["
        translations.forEach { string, translation in
            output += string + ":" + translation + ","
        }
        output = String(output.dropLast())
        output += "]\n"
    }
    
    do {
        try output.write(to: file, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        print("Project \"\(name)\" saved to internal application storage.")
        return true
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return false
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You're not showing all of your code, but using those `$` signs makes it appear that you're trying to pass Bindings into the function. The function, though, takes regular (non-Binding) arguments. What happens if you lose the `$`s?

Comment: Your answer is the solution! I was indeed passing bindings, and didn't realize I shouldn't be using $ signs.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$` character in Swift means that you're passing a `Binding` (or, more specifically, a "projected value" from a property wrapper like `@State` or `@Published`).

Your function, however, takes regular (eg. non-Binding) parameters. Remove the `$`s at your call site and everything should work/